# Selection in first drop down populates data in second dropdown but only on first click, why?

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I have 2 drop downs where selection of first drop down effects the data content of the second drop down.
The problem I have is this functionality is occurring only on first click instead it should happen every time.

Here is my jsFiddle with [my working code](http://jsfiddle.net/sid1404/2tdbd9xt/) and [here](https://jsbin.com/rezeji/edit?html,js,console,output) is my code on jsbin(jsbin gives some error which I am unable to understand, help appreciated here too, #newbieTorture).
Thanks in Advance :)

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.ArticleAdapter= DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({});
App.Article =DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr(),
    body: DS.attr(),
    shouldReloadAll:true,
    comments: DS.hasMany('comment', {async : true})
    //async tells compiler to load data from comment everytime this is rendered
});

App.Comment =DS.Model.extend({
    text: DS.attr(),
    shouldReloadAll:true,
    article: DS.belongsTo('article', { async: true })
});


App.Article.FIXTURES=[ 
      {
        id:1,
        title : 'Ember',
        body:'Its a great technology but need lot of studying and practice',
        comments:[1]
      },{
        id:2,
        title : 'Angular',
        body:'it takes  less understanding but has more coding the ember',
        comments:[2,3]
      //this will be an aray coz it is has many relation
      }
];

App.Comment.FIXTURES=[ 
      {
        id:1,
        text : 'Yyyieee excited to learn ember',
        aricle: 1
        //its not an array coz it will be related to single object
    },{
        id:2,
        text : 'I will start Angular once i have fininshed with ember',
        article: 2
      },{
        id:3,
        text : 'Angular can be interesting',
        article: 2
       }
];


App.CommentAdapter= DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();


App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    articleValue: null,
    selected: null,

    articleStore: Em.computed(function(){
        console.log("data is : " + this.get('articleValue'));
        console.log("data is : " + this.get('selected'));
        return this.store.findAll("article");
    }).property("selected"),

    availableComment: Em.computed(function () {
        var make = this.get('selected');
        // the line below returns the id and not an object
        console.log(make);
        if (make === undefined || make === null)
        return [];
        return this.get('selected').get('comments');
    }).property('articleValue'),

    actions:{
        callIndexController: function(){
            var select= this.get("selected");
            console.log("hi :" + select);
        }
    }
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return [];
    },
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars"> 
        <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
        {{outlet}}
        </script>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
            First drop down: 
                   {{
                         view "select"
                         contentBinding=articleStore
                         optionLabelPath="content.title"
                         optionValuePath="content.id"
                         prompt="Pick a person:"
                         shouldReloadAll=true
                         selectionBinding=selected
                         valueBinding=articleValue
                    }}
            <br>
            <br>
                Second drop down:        
            {{
                 view "select"
                 contentBinding=availableComment
                 optionLabelPath="content.text"
                 optionValuePath="content.id"
                 prompt="related task:"
                 shouldReloadAll=true
                 valueBinding=articleValue
            }}
        </script>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.13.7/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
        <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.13.7/ember.debug.js"></script>
        <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.13.7/ember-data.js"></script>
        <script src="js/amit_dropdown.js"></script>
        <!-- to activate the test runner, add the "?test" query string parameter -->
        <script src="tests/runner.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should not use view to do this. View (and select) are deprecated since a long time. Ember replaced view with component which are more isolated from controllers. Anyway, I know this is not the kind of answer you want, but if you are currently learning Ember like your sample suggest, you should look into components to manage your selects : http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/components/

Comment: @dynamic_cast thanks for making me aware i'll try and update the code,howsoever, if you could tell me what is the problem in this code it would be great help, i am on clock.